# How to search folder name with preg_match

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to search for a folder name in parent folder. My parent folder consists of the below folders.
Parent folder name is **`backup`**

```
26-12-2016_17-26-30_68692e001ee2
26-12-2016_17-27-32_68692e001ee2
26-12-2016_17-26-35_68692e001c88
26-12-2016_17-26-37_68692e001f90
26-12-2016_17-28-12_68692e001f90
26-12-2016_17-30-22_68692e001f90
26-12-2016_17-29-07_68692e001c90
```

How can i get the complete folder names that ends with **`68692e001f90`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be easy if you use  `DirectoryIterator`

Here is the working code for your problem

```
<?php
    $path = 'backup';
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $file) {
         if ($file->isDot()) continue;

        if ($file->isDir()) {

            if(strpos($file->getFilename(), '68692e001f90') !== false){                             
                print $file->getFilename() . '<br />';
                // die;
            }

        }
    }
?>
```

Hope this would help you.